# Movie about aliens taking a child’s mother?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

There was an animated movie I watched around ten years ago about a child whose mom was kidnapped by aliens that wanted to transfer her motherly instincts into robot caretakers for their species. Then, the boy goes on an adventure to save her. Unfortunately, I forgot the name of the movie. *Does anyone have an idea of what it is?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is [**Mars Needs Moms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Needs_Moms):

[image]

> ...The Martians decide to bring Milo's mother to Mars, where her
> "momness" will be extracted and implanted into the next generation of
> nannybots.
>
> Later that night, Milo goes to apologize, but discovers his mom is
> being abducted. He runs after her, but they end up in separate parts
> of the Martian spaceship...

ps. search string: *animation aliens captured mother*

Comment: This movie was based on a children's picture book. I read it once to a class of kindergartners and they all freaked out; crying, balling, "Where's my Mommie!!!"  Sometimes you can't win.

Comment: I just read the plot of that movie.  It's incredibly complicated!  :O

Comment: As a point of parliamentary procedure, this was a terrible move.

Comment: @JavaMikeMoore In what ways?

Comment: @OKprogrammer: [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/mars_needs_moms) says it "suffers from a lack of imagination and heart." Reading through some of the individual reviews, I see a lot of reviewers citing the use of motion capture as a possible source of animation issues. Also, some of them didn't like the plot.

Comment: @JavaMikeMoore I'm shocked, I say